# Ubuntu folder permission /etc

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I recently changed my /etc folder to -R 0770  permission and now everything got messed up. command prompt is not working, after that login is not working, is their any way to get folder permissions back. 
please help , thanks in advance.

Comment: change it back to drwxr-xr-x